# Postfix: different smarthosts per server port

Tags: postfix, smtp

I need to install Postfix and let it listen on two different ports: 1025 and 1026:

```
/etc/postfix/master.cf:

1025      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
1026      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
```

I need two different relayhosts for messages coming from these two ports:

- `relay1.domain.com` for messages coming to the port `1025`
- `relay2.domain.com` for messages coming to the port `1026`

Relay hosts are using different authentications (for this I know I can use the `smtp_sasl_password_maps` option).

What I am able to do is enable the two transports on different ports, but what I am not able to do is to specify different relay hosts for different transport: I know I could use the `transport_maps` option to specify different transport (and relay hosts) for different destinations, but not for different listen ports.

I also know I can create different Postfix instances (with different `master.cf` configuration files), but I would like to keep a single instance so that I don't have to deal with different `systemctl` services.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Read [man 5 master](https://www.postfix.org/master.5.html) carefully:

> A logical line starts with  non-whitespace  text.  A  line  that starts with whitespace continues a logical line.

Usually a line which does start with the whitespace continues the last field of the table and that allows to supply argument to the command in that table.

Knowing that you can set up (override) `smtpd` attributes directly in the `master.cf` via the command line arguments:

```
1025      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
    -o relayhost=[relay1.example.com]
1026      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
    -o relayhost=[relay2.example.com]
```

Square brackets suppress MX lookups (e.g. this will use an A record of `relay1.example.com` instead of looking up MX record of it and then looking A record for that name).

This way you just override the settings of `main.cf` for this particular instance of the daemon.

There should be no spaces in the arguments of "-o" in the `master.cf` (in particular, no spaces around "="), and you can't even use quotes for that. If you need spaces there or you just want to be able to set that up in the `main.cf`, you can declare variables there and reference them in `master.cf`:

`main.cf`:

```
relayhost_1025 = [relay1.example.com]
relayhost_1026 = [relay2.example.com]
```

`master.cf`:

```
1025      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
    -o relayhost=$relayhost_1025
1026      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
    -o relayhost=$relayhost_1026
```

Or, curly brackets could be used to enclose spaces; that described in the manual I linked to, but I never did that myself.

As you probably have guessed, any options can be overridden like this, and you may override multiple options. Even if you look at default `master.cf` closely you may notice the (probably) commented out `submission` service which uses that syntax. There are also usually other services defined that span multiple lines like this. Use it as an example.

Comment: Thank you! I will try!